# React Nextjs - Caminho do parâmetro da undefined após dar Refrech ( F5 ) na página

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, adonisjs, next.js

Obs: Eco Sistemas utilizados aqui: Nextjs, Adonisjs e Mysql

Tenho seguinte código onde faço uma apresentação de notícia, o que ocorre é o seguinte... logo após eu vir da listagem das notícias, e selecionar uma delas ele vem de primeira foto, titulo, subtitulo e texto da notícia de boa `{id: 1, category: "Guga Teste 01", fileimg: "eu.png", maintitle: "Guga Teste 01", subtitle: "Guga Teste 01", …}`porem.... se eu der um F5 nessa tela o caminho some e dá um: `GET http://localhost:3333/news/images/undefined 404 (Not Found)`, não consigo identificar o que ocorre se alguém já tiver passado por algo o tipo por favor me ajude, desde já agradeço toda a atenção. segue código:

```
import axios from 'axios'
// import Link from 'next/link'
import { URL_API } from '../utils/config'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function PageNoticiasInterna(props) {

    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
            async function loadingNotice() {

                //fazendo conexão com a API e BANCO DE DADOS
               //Requisição ajax
                const response = await axios.get(URL_API + '/news/' + props.id)

                console.log(response.data)
                setData({ ...response.data })
            }

            if (props.id) {
                loadingNotice()
            }
            console.log(props.id)
        }
        , [])


    return (
        <section className="noticias-interna">
            <section className="hero is-medium is-bold img-full-insise">
                <div className="hero-body">
                    <div className="container has-text-centered">
                        <h1 className="title is-size-3 is-size-5-mobile pb-2 has-text-white">
                            Notícias
                        </h1>
                        <p className="subtitle is-size-5 is-size-7-mobile has-text-white">
                            Fique por dentro de tudo que acontece no mundo Jurídico
                        </p>
                        <nav className="breadcrumb is-centered" aria-label="breadcrumbs">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Práticas Jurídicas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" className="is-active" aria-current="page">Notícias</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section className="section">
                <section className="noticia">
                    <div className="container is-light">
                        <div className="columns">
                            <div className="column is-three-quarters">
                                <figure className="image is-3by1 is-720x240 mb-5">
                                    <img src={URL_API + '/news/images/' + data.fileimg} />
                                </figure>
                                <h1 className="is-size-2 has-text-left has-text-weight-bold has-text-left-mobile">{data.maintitle}</h1>
                                <h2 className="is-size-5 has-text-left has-text-weight-light has-text-left-mobile">{data.subtitle}</h2>

                                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.new }} className="text-notice-space"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <figure className="image is-4by5 is-480x600 mb-5">
                                    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x600.png" />
                                </figure>
                                <figure className="image is-4by5 is-480x600">
                                    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x600.png" />
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section className="section">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="columns">
                            <div className="column is-three-quarters">
                                <figure className="image is-3by1 is-720x240 mb-5">
                                    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/720x240.png" />
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo a requisição com o `id` de uma `Promise` dentro do `useEffect`. Então quando você atualizar a pagina seu `props.id` é `undefined` por padrão.
Experimente salvar seu objeto no `state` da aplicação.

Para manipular o estado globalmente se necessário sugiro [React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start)